# Perform Rust type conversion without unwrapping Option

Tags: rust, enums

Is there more elegant way of converting option enum to option integer than unwrapping it?

```rust
enum SomeEnum {
    Item1 = 0,
    Item2 = 1
}

fn main() {
    let value = SomeEnum::Item1;
    let option_integer: Option<i16> = value.into();
}
```

the trait bound `std::option::Option<i16>: From<std::option::Option<SomeEnum>>` is not satisfied.

This works, however I consider this code unnecessary boilerplate:

```rust
enum SomeEnum {
    Item1 = 0,
    Item2 = 1
}

fn main() {
    let value = Some(SomeEnum::Item1);
    let option_integer: Option<i16> = match value {
        Some(some_enum) => Some(some_enum as i16),
        None => None
    };
}
```

Comment: Your second snippet doesn't compile. Did you mean to make `value` an `Option<SemeEnum>`?

Comment: What about `(value as i16).into()`?

Comment: Or `Option::from(value as i16)`

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description nor the error message. Should we read `let value = Some (SomeEnum::Item1);` for both samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) to create an `Option` of a different type applying a function to the value contained with within an `Option`:

```
let option_integer = value.map(|x| x as i16);
```

Comment: It'll require you to specify types, like `Option::from(value).map(|x| x as i16)`